# how to refine/filter search result from mysql database using php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, xhtml

i am trying to develop my website and need some support. so my web page searches for a product's information and return an appropriate result.It works perfectly fine when user search through a keyword or product title in search box and submit the query but now with the list of result obtained,  i want a filter search where the user is able to filter their search result according to price, brand, category, etc.

i have two tables in the mysql database
1 : product_info with columns
productid, title, description, brand, category, price
2: product_image
productid,imageid,imagename,image

please help me on how about i should begin with the process. i have looked on net and their are multiple suggestions on which script to use but i want to work with the simplest approach since i am new to all this. you can suggest anything related to this topic.Thank you:)

just to let you know, for single search box i used the following code.

```
$query= "
    SELECT * 
    FROM `product_info`
    WHERE `title` LIKE '% ".$search_name." %'
    OR `title` LIKE '% ".$search_name."'
    OR `title` LIKE '".$search_name." %'
    OR `title` = '".$search_name."'";

    $query_run=mysql_query($query);


    if(mysql_num_rows($query_run)>=1) 

    {
        echo'Showing '.mysql_num_rows($query_run).' results for items with "'.$search_name.'" in    the title:';

//the result is displayed in the table format.

}
```

Comment: why not add a `AND price BETWEEN 0 AND 200` to your SQL?

Comment: Use an AND with the second query.

Comment: "SELECT * FROM 'Product_info' WHERE 'title' LIKE '% ".$search_name." %' AND 'price' > '150' and 'brand' LIKE '% ".$brand_name." %'

or are you asking how to dynamically modify a query string depending on what checkbox or dropdown is selected?

Comment: i thought of that but when the i tried to add a form with drop down list of multiple price, ,brand and category it refreshed the whole search and displayed the result all over again.plus i cudn't get the search_name from the first form to display in the new form with all the categories. so i thought there might be an easier way to just filter the result without having to do overall search again??

Comment: @Brutnus i am looking for dynamically modifying a query string depending on what checkbox or dropdown is selected. but don't know how to start.

Comment: Maybe the best solution is to have 3 input texts. 1 for Brand, 1 for price, 1 for name.

Comment: Reason i say that is. PHP doesn't do dynamic client side. Javascript/jquery does that.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is that you don't use php for this. The whole idea of having a database is that you run queries against it in order to select data from it based on criteria. So you build a suitable WHERE clause for your query which will pull only the rows that match the criteria requested by the user.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. so is there any suggestions which script i should work with??

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "which script i should work with?".  You will need to have a way for the users to specify which property (price, brand, ...) they wish to apply their filters to. Maybe you give them select boxes, it's really up to you.